# Simple state machine based command-line argument parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, state-machine

I'm in the process of learning to write idiomatic JavaScript code so naturally I'm parsing command line arguments.

My approach to this is to have a simple state machine. The parser should work as follows:

To get tags pass to the application, you would do the following:

```
application tag tag1 tag2
```

The parser raises an event when the requirements are met. To register an event for a particular token, you would:

```
parser.registerAction({
        tag: function(token, result) {
          // do stuff with tag arguments
        }
});
```

You can see the usage in some tests [here](https://github.com/bdurrani/node-hey/blob/master/test/parsertests.js).

To get names, you dont need to specify the token. You just write out the names:

```
application name1 name2
```

You can register to get the names values the same way as tags.

This is kinda based on the generic [`CommandParser`](https://github.com/arieh/CommandParser). I just wanted to write up something myself.

I'm mostly looking for feedback about writing idiomatic JS code. My background is mostly C# and some C++ and I'm trying to change the way I think about code.

The code actually lives [here](https://github.com/bdurrani/node-hey/blob/master/parser.js).

```
class Parser {
    constructor(args) {

        /**
         * arguments being parsed
         **/
        this._args = args;

        /**
         * stores the registered actions callbacks
         **/
        this._actions = {};

        /**
         * stores the values associated with the tokens
         **/
        this._actionValues = {};

        /**
         * current state of the state machine
         **/
        this._currentState = this.endCommandState;

        /**
         * current token being parsed
         **/
        this._currentValue = '';
    }

    get listToken() {
        return 'list';
    }

    get tagToken() {
        return 'tag';
    }

    get nameToken() {
        return 'names';
    }

    _isReservedToken(token) {
        let reservedTokens = [
            this.tagToken,
            this.listToken
        ];

        return reservedTokens.indexOf(token) > -1;
    }

    _getCommandFromToken(token) {
        if (token === this.listToken) {
            return this.listCommandState;
        }

        if (token === this.tagToken) {
            return this.tagCommandState;
        }

        // name requires no token
        return this.namesCommandState;
    }

    _raiseRegisteredAction(token) {
        if (this._actions[token]) {
            this._actions[token](token, this._actionValues);
        }
        this._actionValues = [];
    }

    parse() {
        if (this._args.length == 0) {
            console.log('nothing to parse');
            return;
        }

        if (!this._getNextValue()) {
            this._currentState = this.endCommandState;
            return;
        }

        this._currentState = this._getCommandFromToken(this._currentValue);
        // if (this._isReservedToken(this._currentValue)) {

        while (this._currentState !== this.endCommandState) {
            this._currentState();
        }

        // the final state
        this._currentState();
    }

    endCommandState() {
        console.log('parsing ended');
    }

    namesCommandState() {
        const token = this.nameToken;
        this._actionValues[token] = this._actionValues[token] || [];
        this._actionValues[token].push(this._currentValue.toLowerCase());

        this._currentState = this._getNextValue() ?
            this.namesCommandState : this.endCommandState;

        if (this._currentState === this.endCommandState) {
            this._raiseRegisteredAction(token);
        }       
    }

    listCommandState() {
        const token = this.listToken;
        this._actionValues[token] = [];
        this._raiseRegisteredAction(token);
        this._currentState = this.endCommandState;
    }

    tagCommandState() {
        const token = this.tagToken;
        this._actionValues[token] = [];
        if (this._getNextValue()) {
            this._currentState = this.tagEventIdCommandState;
        }
        else {
            this._currentState = this.endCommandState;
        }
    }

    tagEventIdCommandState() {
        const token = this.tagToken;
        this._actionValues[token].push({
            eventid: this._currentValue
        });
        if (this._getNextValue()) {
            this._currentState = this.tagValueCommandState;
        }
        else {
            this._raiseRegisteredAction(token);
            this._currentState = this.endCommandState;
        }
    }

    tagValueCommandState() {
        const token = this.tagToken;
        this._actionValues[token].push({
            tagValue: this._currentValue
        });
        if (this._getNextValue()) {
            this._currentState = this.tagValueCommandState;
        }
        else {
            this._raiseRegisteredAction(token);
            this._currentState = this.endCommandState;
        }
    }

    _getNextValue() {
        let currentValue = this._args.shift();
        if (currentValue) {
            this._currentValue = currentValue;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    registerAction(action) {
        Object.assign(this._actions, action);
    }
}

module.exports = Parser;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use an if/else statement here

> ```
> _getCommandFromToken(token) {
>     if (token === this.listToken) {
>         return this.listCommandState;
>     }
>
>     if (token === this.tagToken) {
>         return this.tagCommandState;
>     }
>
>     // name requires no token
>     return this.namesCommandState;
> }
> ```

like this:

```
_getCommandFromToken(token) {
    if (token === this.listToken) {
        return this.listCommandState;
    } else if (token === this.tagToken) {
        return this.tagCommandState;
    } else {
        // name requires no token
        return this.namesCommandState;
    }
}
```

I think that the comment is good here, but I haven't read the rest of the code thoroughly yet.

---

I also noticed that you are using a bracing style that differs from what most use.

> ```
>     if (this._getNextValue()) {
>         this._currentState = this.tagValueCommandState;
>     }
>     else {
>         this._raiseRegisteredAction(token);
>         this._currentState = this.endCommandState;
>     }
> ```

you should put the else on the same line as the trailing brace of the if statement.

```
if (this._getNextValue()) {
    this._currentState = this.tagValueCommandState;
} else {
    this._raiseRegisteredAction(token);
    this._currentState = this.endCommandState;
}
```